# Store files to a list with ls, while removing parts of the dirname with sed

Tags: linux

I have a folder lets say located here:

`/Users/spotter/Downloads`

and within the root folder there are two files:

`test1.txt` and `test2.txt`.

I want to write a shell script to save all the files to a list with a line like this:

`file_list="$(ls /Users/spotter/Downloads)"`

and `echo $file_list` will return:

`/Users/spotter/Downloads/test1.txt`
`/Users/spotter/Downloads/test2.txt`

However I want to change part of the dirname. Particularly I want to remove the `/Users/spotter` part.

I tried this like so:

`file_list="$(ls /Users/spotter/Downloads |
while read path; do dirname "$path"  | sed 's/users/spotter///'; done)"`

which returns:

`sed: 1: "s/users/spotter/Downloa ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'D'`

`sed: 1: "s/users/spotter/Downloa ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'D'`

when I do `echo $file_list` I want this to be the output:

`Downloads/test1.txt`
`Downloads/test2.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that sed thinks '/' is the delimiter between the RE and the substitution, so sed is not reading the other '/'s the way you want it to. You can use other characters as a delimiter. For instance `'s~/Users/spotter/~~'`.